# Extract custom icons from Word 2000 template

Tags: template, microsoft-office, icons

I'm upgrading some custom templates/macros from Word 2000 to Word 2010.  There are custom icons that are embedded in the .dot template files.  I'd like to use those same icons for my new Ribbon - does anyone know how to extract the icons from the old .Dot file?

Answer (score 1):

You can open the .dot files by using a zip extraction program such as 7-zip.

In there you will find the icon files.